# Записать формулу иначе

Tags: excel

Привет :). 
Нахожу число Пи методом Монте-Карло,а также вероятность попадания в единичный квадрат параболы. В столбцах D и Е нашёл точки попадания использовав условие "Если".
Как записать по-другому формулу точек попадания? 
Вот ссылка файла [файла](http://yadi.sk/d/NhIWhEVO9KLyS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понял вопрос.

В столбце *С* можно:

```
=--(A2^2+B2^2 <=1)
```

Если без столбца *С*:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2^2+B2^2 <=1;A2;)
=ЕСЛИ(A2^2+B2^2 <=1;B2;)
```

Или

```
=(A2^2+B2^2<=1)*A2
=(A2^2+B2^2<=1)*B2
```

Но так хуже.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Я хочу спросить вот что. К примеру у столбца D формула =ЕСЛИ(C2=1;A2;0),как изменить формулу так, чтобы получались такие же значения что и в столбце D?

Comment: Объясните: формула в столбце D и хотите получить значение той же ячейки?
Покажите на примере

Comment: Получить значения что и в D столбце использовав другую формулу

Comment: Зачем?! Какой смысл менять простую рабочую формулу?

Comment: Вот такой я зануда ))

Comment: =(A2^2+B2^2<=1)*A2
Но так хуже.

Comment: а для столбца Е как будет? :)

Comment: Добавил в ответ.